# Highcharts multiple rowsUrl in same charts

Tags: highcharts

How can I show multiple series with rowsUrl?

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/data/livedata-rows

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'spline'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Live Data (Rows JSON)'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: 'Data input from a remote JSON file'
  },

  data: {
    rowsURL: 'https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/time-rows.json',
    firstRowAsNames: false,
    enablePolling: true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `seriesMapping` property:

```
data: {
    ...,
    seriesMapping: [{
        x: 0,
        y: 1
    }, {
        x: 0,
        y: 2
    }]
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k8gt2vLp/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.seriesMapping

Comment: how to split different data for series 1 and series 2.I mean different x value and different y value.live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ga1u4zLk/

Comment: Hi Mansour BRAHMI, Could you describe more precisely how do you want to parse data?

Comment: Hi ppotaczek, Thank you for your time.I find the solution.live Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/oh95rgpz/